Add custom class to drupal 9 menu item
I have been working on website which is prepared in Drupal 9. I need to apply custom class
to menu item to trigger some other events. I come across changes in code as per below link:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274500/add-classes-to-the-menu-item-li

There are other answers available at SO for adding ID / Class to Drupal menu item from code.
Is there any way can we add ID / Class from Drupal admin interface and apply to individual menu item?

I think you can use the module menu_atttributes : https://www.drupal.org/project/menus_attribute .
with that you can add class to menu item
